# Switch from SQL Server Express to SQL Server Developer edition on the same computer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, ssms-2017

My computer has at least 3 installations of SQL Server:

- SQL Server 2017 64 bits for the Express edition. I can connect with SSMS with `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`. Version is 14.0.1000
- SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition. I can connect with SSMS with localhost. Version is 14.0.2027.2
- SQL Server 2016 LocalDB. Don't know how to connect with SSMS. Version is 13.1.4000.0

I have looked inside H`KLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL` and found :

- `MSSQLSERVER` (which is the default instance name, right ?)
- `SQLEXPRESS` which is the Express version

So, the 2016 LocalDB is not used anymore by any application? (including Visual Studio)

In `SSMS` which command should I use to connect to `MSSQLSERVER` or `SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: On Server Name put: . (for local connection); this will connect to `MSSQLSERVER ` default instance, for the `SQLEXPRESS ` instance put: .\ SQLEXPRESS

Comment: `LocalDB` is a feature of SQL Server Express, meant for *development*, not a "real" separate instance. You need to install SQL Server Express to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect to your default instance on your local machine, use this as your "server/instance" name:

```
.
(local)
localhost
your-machine-name
your-ip-address
```

For the default instance, you **must NOT** specify the `MSSQLSERVER` "instance" name...

And if the SQL Server is on another machine, you need to use either that remote machine's machine name (or the IP address) for connecting to it.

For any other instance, you need to use any of the above, *plus* you need to add the **instance name** to it - in your case, for SQL Server Express, it defaults to `SQLEXPRESS`, so use

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
localhost\SQLEXPRESS
your-machine-name\SQLEXPRESS
your-ip-address\SQLEXPRESS
```

The LocalDB is *not* handled the same as the other editions - it is **not** by default started as Windows startup, but it only gets started when your Visual Studio solution is run (and therefore needs to use the LocalDB instance). With the `SqlLocalDB` utility (see [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) ), you can also explicitly start up a LocalDB instance (and shut it down again, too).

Comment: very instructive answer thanks :).
is there a way in T-SQL script to select the default instance or the named instance ? (the T-SQL script can be run inside SSMS or with sqlcmd)

Comment: @NolmëInformatique: no, in SSMS, you have to **first** decide what instance to connect to - once there, you cannot "switch" to another instance inside SSMS from within T-SQL - you need to add a second, separate connection